# Creating memory efficient objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-efficient

Suppose I have a Contact object with a name and photo only

```
@interface Contact: NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    UIImage *photo;
}
@property (copy) NSString name;
@property (copy) UIImage photo;
```

suppose further that I live in a place where I have 1000 people called Sam and they're all clones so their photo look exactly the same and I decided to cheat and use the same photo for all of them.

Is Objective C smart enough that when a copy of the name and photo is taken it would recognise it has the same value and can be handled by one object and allocate just one NSString and one UIImage for all the Sams?

What is the correct way to handle this? Clearly I do need to make the them copy properties to handle non Sam cases and in case I get passed mutable strings and images.

Comment: Languages are only as smart as the programmer. If you tell it to use the same object it will do so, otherwise it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage` doesn't conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, so the question is fairly moot. You need to change that `copy` on the `photo` property to a `retain`. This is perfectly fine for you since `UIImage` isn't mutable anyway (and has no mutable subclasses), so there's no need to copy it.

As for the name, calling `-copy` on immutable objects (that support copying) tends to just retain the object instead of copying it. Calling it on the mutable variant of these objects (e.g. `NSMutableString`) will produce an immutable copy (which will itself respond to subsequent `-copy` requests by retaining). Note, however, that calling `-copy` on a mutable object multiple times will produce distinct immutable copies.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [UIImage imageNamed:] then the sdk will cache the photo for you and reuse it. Also, since UIImage is immutable you can't really change it after it has been loaded into memory.

> Image objects are immutable, so you cannot change their properties
>   after creation. This means that you generally specify an image’s
>   properties at initialization time or rely on the image’s metadata to
>   provide the property value.

If you want to make your Contact conform to NSCopying, just make sure you use copy on the NSString when duplicating your objects.